# Looping through array works fine in python but not with Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my flask app i am trying to display an array of posts from the database as indepedent items with Jinja2. I've managed to loop all of the text information and it works fine, but when i try to render the image urls, i only get the first item to repeat.

In my python code i did it like the following:

```
res = supabase.table('posts').select('name').execute()
ids = res['data']
 for e in ids:
  e_p = supabase.table('users').select('profile_picture').eq('name', e['name']).execute()
  print(e_p['data'])
return render_template('feed.html', each_pic=e_p)
```

and i got the results i wanted (only the last url is different from the others)

```
[{'profile_picture': 'https://i0.wp.com/www.finisgeekis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/lain-alien.jpg?w=398&ssl=1'}]
[{'profile_picture': 'https://i0.wp.com/www.finisgeekis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/lain-alien.jpg?w=398&ssl=1'}]
[{'profile_picture': 'https://i0.wp.com/www.finisgeekis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/lain-alien.jpg?w=398&ssl=1'}]
[{'profile_picture': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTYwNjM5ZTAtNTBlMy00ZjNkLTkxNDUtZGQ0YzExODQ3Yjc4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgzMjQ1NDg@._V1_FMjpg_UX1012_.jpg'}]
```

However when i passed it as a variable and tried to render the values using Jinja2 like this:

```
{% for ep in each_pic['data'] %}
 <img class="small_pic rounded-circle" src={{ep}}/>
{% endfor %}
```

I only got the first image repeated for every item for some reason.

I'm very new to python in general so i can't see what would cause that to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode [how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Can you verify that the data you get is that blob that looks like a list of lists?

Comment: If i try to render the data as text, it returns just the first item and only once, if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: You say that when you `print(e_p['data'])` you get the follow on result, but that result seems odd to me.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand before, but yes, printing the database query directly or just "e_p" also gives me the correct result on the console. It returns 'data' that contains the urls as i need them and 'status_code'.

Comment: The result on the console looks like a print statement was called four times each time printing a single list. So I agree with JonSG its odd.

Comment: You're right, i believe the question is missing context. The "e['name']'" on the database query is the result of a different query that returns 4 values, that's probably why. I'll edit it now with the missing part.

Comment: Mind fixing the indentation? e.g. `for e in ids:` cannot have the next line be at the same indentation.

Comment: You'll have to show us the render call for the template, and show us how the `each_pic` variable was created.

Comment: just edited it with the render_template line, i passed 'each_pic' as a variable for 'e_p'

Comment: This needs a [mcve].